# Rails 5.1 ActiveJob on Puma development not performing specific enqueued job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, rails-activejob, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm running Rails 5.1.4 server (Puma v. 3.10.0 in single mode), but having an issue with a specific ActionJob that get's enqueued correctly but often never performed.

I have a handful of jobs. All but 1 specific job always gets performed asynchronously like expected shortly after enqueuing them.

First time after a server restart my specific job gets performed correctly after a new queueing. But after the first successful run, it will not get performed on following enqueuings.

I'm queueing all jobs generally with `perform_later`.

I've tested queuing the specific job using `rails console` as well. Whenever I queue it in the console, it gets performed instantly. Even in same session. Also tried with same arguments as used in the application when it's getting queued in the `rails server`, but in server it only gets queued. Never performed.

I've checked the log files - there is nothing, no errors, no fatals, no warnings. It simply states `[ActiveJob] Enqueued FooBaaJob`, but never performs the job.

If the job actually failed, it should at least still get to write out `[ActiveJob] [FooBaaJob] [id] Performing FooBaaJob` in the log, but it doesn't.
And per https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/logging.rb#L78 it should actually catch and log the exception if it was failing. Secondly it never fails to run in console, so that shouldn't be the case.

Any ideas about where to look?

Comment: What do you have your job queue set to for your development environment?

Comment: `async` (default - not set explicitly) and all jobs in `default` queue. Whenever I try to run the job queue `inline` it always executes the job successfully.

Comment: And you're passing a configuration to Puma only allowing one thread? This is maybe your problem, as `async` will spawn a new Thread?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's single threaded as I'm just using `rails server` command with no additional Puma config than default. However all my other jobs runs as expected, it's only this one specific job that fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found a way to debug this issue.

By creating an initializer file in `config/initializers` with this line:
`Concurrent.use_stdlib_logger(Logger::DEBUG)`

I now get error data output to my console.

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued FooBaaJob (Job ID: ...) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0...0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://test-app/FooBaa/8>>
[2017-10-29 16:10:56.676] DEBUG -- : Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find FooBaa with 'id'=8 (ActiveJob::DeserializationError)
```

*The second line is the result of adding the `Concurrent.use_stdlib_logger(Logger::DEBUG)` initiator file.*

In my case I'm initiating the job in an `after_create` in my model and I'm guessing the job executions happens instantaneously in a manner, that results in the record not fully being committed to the sqlite db yet when ActiveJob is trying to load it. It did test this on MySQL as well, same result.

Rails 5.0 introduced `after_[create|update|destroy]_commit`, so changing my `after_create` to `after_create_commit` fixed my issue and the job is now running as expected each time I'm trying.

For earlier versions of Rails you could have moved to `after_commit` with an `on: :create` argument or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly the same cause of this issue: used `afrer_create` callback for starting job.
However, the debugging solution using `Concurrent.use_stdlib_logger(Logger::DEBUG)` seems to be outdated: at least my IDE complains that `Concurrent.use_stdlib_logger` call is deprecated.